# How to forcefully open a link in browser rather than in web-view

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, qr-code

I have made qr code which points to my website. my website is heavily using javascript and jquery.

My problem is whenever i scans the qr code with third party android `"qr code reader"` application it opens the link in WEB view and not in web browser. with web-view my site is not working properly since it doesn't support java-script and jquery by default. i can't enable the javascript in web-view because it is a third party application and i don't have control on it.

I want to know that if there is any way to enable javascript and jquery in `third party` android application or can we force the qr code to open in web browser?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(YOUR_URL));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this looks like an android code. i don't have control on third party android application which i am using. so can't add this code. i have control only on my javascript and html file.

Comment: webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});

Comment: try this @user2274074 it may help you